# Suggest a maven repository manager for my projects

Tags: java, maven, repository

I would like to use a repository manager to accommodate my local and remote jar..But i am a newbie to maven.. So any suggestions among these repository managers .. :)

archetype
apache archiva
sonatype nexus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Nexus from Sonatype and are happy with it so far. Sonatype is quite deep into Maven ("The company was founded by Jason van Zyl, the creator of Apache Maven", http://www.sonatype.com/company.html), which gives additional trust.

Comment: I think there is a free and a commercial (with additional features) version.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least four:

- [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)
- [Reposilite](https://reposilite.com/)

All are available for open source projects.